# Initialize struct with default values, returns null (custom Matrix4x4 struct)

Tags: c#

I am creating my own Matrix4x4 struct but the problem that I have is, if I don't give it any values for the parameter when I create a `new Mat4x4()`, then it will be null rather then setting it to the default parameters, when looking at it in debug mode it temporarily sets the values in the constructor but then goes back to null.

Struct code:

```
public readonly struct Mat4x4
{
    public static Mat4x4 Identity { get; } = new Mat4x4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    private readonly double[] matrix;

    public Mat4x4(double m00 = 1, double m01 = 0, double m02 = 0, double m03 = 0, double m10 = 0, double m11 = 1, double m12 = 0, double m13 = 0, double m20 = 0, double m21 = 0, double m22 = 1, double m23 = 0, double m30 = 0, double m31 = 0, double m32 = 0, double m33 = 1)
    {
        matrix = new double[] { m00, m01, m02, m03, m10, m11, m12, m13, m20, m21, m22, m23, m30, m31, m32, m33 };
    }

    public double this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            return (matrix[row * 4 + column]);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = $"[ {matrix[0]} , {matrix[1]} , {matrix[2]} , {matrix[3]} ]\n" +
                     $"[ {matrix[4]} , {matrix[5]} , {matrix[6]} , {matrix[7]} ]\n" +
                     $"[ {matrix[8]} , {matrix[9]} , {matrix[10]} , {matrix[11]} ]\n" +
                     $"[ {matrix[12]} , {matrix[13]} , {matrix[14]} , {matrix[15]} ]";
        return str;
    }
}
```

This will will throw an error because `matrix = null`:

```
Mat4x4 testMatrix = new Mat4x4();
Debug.Log(testMatrix.ToString());
```

But this will work, and set the matrix to correct default values:

```
Mat4x4 testMatrix = new Mat4x4(m00:1);
Debug.Log(testMatrix.ToString());
```

The way I want it  to work is that If I don't give it any parameters it should set the values to the same as `Identity`, also I want to have the option to only set selected values like `new Mat4x4(m02:2,m13:5)` and still have the rest set to `Identity`

**EDIT:**

Skipping the use of `double[]`

```
public readonly struct Mat4x4
{
    public static Mat4x4 Identity { get; } = new Mat4x4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    public double M00 { get; }
    public double M01 { get; }
    public double M02 { get; }
    public double M03 { get; }
    public double M10 { get; }
    public double M11 { get; }
    public double M12 { get; }
    public double M13 { get; }
    public double M20 { get; }
    public double M21 { get; }
    public double M22 { get; }
    public double M23 { get; }
    public double M30 { get; }
    public double M31 { get; }
    public double M32 { get; }
    public double M33 { get; }

    public Mat4x4(double m00 = 0, double m01 = 0, double m02 = 0, double m03 = 0, double m10 = 0, double m11 = 0, double m12 = 0, double m13 = 0, double m20 = 0, double m21 = 0, double m22 = 0, double m23 = 0, double m30 = 0, double m31 = 0, double m32 = 0, double m33 = 0)
    {
        M00 = m00; M01 = m01; M02 = m02; M03 = m03;
        M10 = m10; M11 = m11; M12 = m12; M13 = m13;
        M20 = m20; M21 = m21; M22 = m22; M23 = m23;
        M30 = m30; M31 = m31; M32 = m32; M33 = m33;
    }

    public double this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[row * 4 + column];
        }
    }

    public double this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: return M00;
                case 1: return M01;
                case 2: return M02;
                case 3: return M03;
                case 4: return M10;
                case 5: return M11;
                case 6: return M12;
                case 7: return M13;
                case 8: return M20;
                case 9: return M21;
                case 10: return M22;
                case 11: return M23;
                case 12: return M30;
                case 13: return M31;
                case 14: return M32;
                case 15: return M33;
                default: return M00;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"[ {M00} , {M01} , {M02} , {M03} ]\n" +
        $"[ {M10} , {M11} , {M12} , {M13} ]\n" +
        $"[ {M20} , {M21} , {M22} , {M23} ]\n" +
        $"[ {M30} , {M31} , {M32} , {M33} ]";
}
```

`var myMat = new Mat4x4()` will default  as 0,0,0,0... and for identity matrix `var myMat = Mat4x4.Identity`

Comment: Why `struct`? Use `class` and parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that - at least not in a very simple way. `new Mat4x4` will always initialize every field to the default value - which is `null` for any reference type, including arrays.

What you *can* do is treat a null array as equivalent to the one in `Identity` via a `Matrix` property which is used *everywhere* within the code.

```cs
public readonly struct Mat4x4
{
    public static Mat4x4 Identity { get; } = new Mat4x4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    // Storage only - might be null.
    private readonly double[] matrix;

    // Use this everywhere, and it will never be null.
    private double[] Matrix => matrix ?? Identity.matrix;

    public Mat4x4(double m00 = 1, double m01 = 0, double m02 = 0, double m03 = 0, double m10 = 0, double m11 = 1, double m12 = 0, double m13 = 0, double m20 = 0, double m21 = 0, double m22 = 1, double m23 = 0, double m30 = 0, double m31 = 0, double m32 = 0, double m33 = 1)
    {
        matrix = new double[] { m00, m01, m02, m03, m10, m11, m12, m13, m20, m21, m22, m23, m30, m31, m32, m33 };
    }

    public double this[int row, int column] => Matrix[row * 4 + column];

    public override string ToString() =>
         $"[ {Matrix[0]} , {Matrix[1]} , {Matrix[2]} , {Matrix[3]} ]\n" +
         $"[ {Matrix[4]} , {Matrix[5]} , {Matrix[6]} , {Matrix[7]} ]\n" +
         $"[ {Matrix[8]} , {Matrix[9]} , {Matrix[10]} , {Matrix[11]} ]\n" +
         $"[ {Matrix[12]} , {Matrix[13]} , {Matrix[14]} , {Matrix[15]} ]";
}
```

Note that the property is still private, and needs to be - otherwise the array might be mutated.

Comment: This works exactly how I want it, but is there any extra performance cost doing it this way? I would think its essentially doing an `if matrix == null return Identity else return matrix` check every time you access a value?

Comment: @PatrikFröhler: Yes, it will be doing exactly that. There's a performance implication, but whether that's *important* or not will depend on your application. Assuming your struct actually has multiple other methods, in each of those you might want to take a local copy of the property value before using it multiple times.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I might have to re think a bit, I am currently re-writing my old Matrix4x4 to try improve the performance, I assume having to make a copy of matrix when I want to use the values in a methods also have some performance cost to it. I might try do it without an double array and store the values individually, but accessing becomes tricky, if you have another suggestions I would happily hear them.

Comment: @PatrikFröhler: It's also worth noting that while your identity matrix is a natural default value for *multiplication*, it's definitely not a good default for other things - such as addition. It's a bit like defaulting an `int` variable to 1. You might just want to leave it as it is, and accept that the default value is invalid.

Comment: I created a version that don't use an array (_see EDIT_), and yeah it will default to 0 and is probably better, and then if I want it as Identity I have to explicitly set it to `= Mat4x4.Identity` I looked at my old Matrix4x4 struct and I don't actually loop thru the values at any point so I do not really need Indexers.

Answer (score -1):

You could declare you own private default constructor:

```
public readonly struct Mat4x4 
{

    private Mat4x4()
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope, you can't declare parameterless constructors in structs.

Comment: Yeah that is something I have already tried, probably should have mentioned it, and well that does not work with structs.